# linux sed find replace content on the same line

Tags: linux, sed, text-search

```
export const CURRENT_VERSION = '1.0.61 (2018.07.13.22.32) - UAT1'
export const CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.TEST1
export const environmentVariable = getEnvironmentFile(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT)
```

app.js file content is as above.

I am trying to replace the content of the file, during the build time as below

```
sh "./envScript 'app.js' 2 \"$VERSION_NUMBER ($BUILD_NUMBER) - PROD\""
```

and my envScript.sh is as below

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# == 3 ]; then
    sed -i '' '/export const CURRENT_VERSION =/d' $1
    sed -i '' '/export const CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT =/d' $1
    sed -i '' '$a\
    export var CURRENT_VERSION = '"'$3'" $1
    case $2 in
        0)
            sed -i '' '$a\
            export var CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.UAT1' $1
        ;;
        1)
            sed -i '' '$a\
            export var CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.UAT2' $1
        ;;
        2)
            sed -i '' '$a\
            export var CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.PROD' $1
        ;;
    esac
else
    echo "You need to pass AppConfig.js path as a parameter"
fi
```

**problem**, this works partially, but always, updates the CURRENT_VERSION and CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT , towards the end of the file, due to which `getEnvironmentFile(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT)` defaults to `CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT=undefined` option , since

```
export const CURRENT_VERSION = '1.0.61 (2018.07.13.22.32) - UAT1'
```

goes at the end of the file.

**requested help** : how can we use sed to do inplace edits at the same line in the file, basically find and replace in this situation , so that `getEnvironmentFile(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT)`  would always find `CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT` before calling, and won't default to undefined. Any help is really appreciated.

Original app.js before running the script

```
export const CURRENT_VERSION = '1.0.61 (2018.07.13.22.32) - UAT1'
export const CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.TEST1
export const environmentVariable = getEnvironmentFile(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT)
```

currently modified app.js

after running the command

```
sh "./envScript '../../App/Config/AppConfig.js' 2 \"$VERSION_NUMBER ($BUILD_NUMBER) - PROD\""
```

updated file

```
export const environmentVariable = getEnvironmentFile(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT)
export const CURRENT_VERSION = '1.0.61 (2018.07.13.22.32) - PROD'
export const CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.PROD
```

expected result

```
export const CURRENT_VERSION = '1.0.61 (2018.07.13.22.32) - PROD'
export const CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT = ENVIRONMENT.PROD
export const environmentVariable = getEnvironmentFile(CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT)
```

Comment: What's the desired output exactly?

Comment: AND show a typical call to your script with values for $1,$2,$3. Good luck.

Comment: Also, you say "inplace edits", "find and replace" but your `sed` code is always appending to the end of the file `$a\...`. (which might work). So we need to see your required output sample. Good luck.

Comment: my bad, have edited the information

Comment: very good update to your Q. But its really late for me. Ping tomorrow if you're still having trouble. AND clarify how you can call the script once, but get 3 expected outputs. I see 2 lines getting appended for each call to `./envScript`. Good luck.

Comment: Yep having the same trouble . Please help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is exactly what shellter says it is. Instead of using `$a`, you need to use `s`, like this:

```
 sed '/VERSION/s/UAT1/PROD/;/ENVIRONMENT/s/TEST1/PROD/' app.js
```